# How to change head elements of a page when using ui:composition

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, templating

I want to ask a question that i have a master template like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <div id="top">
            <ui:insert name="top">
                <ui:include src="header.xhtml" id="header"/>
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="content">
                <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom" style="position: absolute;top: 675px;width: 100%" align="center">
            <ui:insert name="bottom">
                <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" id="footer"/>
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

On my each page i am using something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>City Setup</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="./WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form id="cityReviewform">
                    ......
                </h:form>

            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Now what is happening that because of the ui;composition my tile attribute is now working on each page, because ui:composition discard every tag outside of it. Now on each page i have a title of Login(i.e of master template). So i want to ask that how can i do this that on each page, its own title shown instead of Login(master tempalte title)?

Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In the template client, *everything* outside `<ui:composition>` is **ignored**. You need to change your template approach to provide an `<ui:insert>` for the title in the master template, so that it can be defined by an `<ui:define>` in the template client.

Master template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title><ui:insert name="title">Login</ui:insert></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <div id="top">
            <ui:insert name="top">
                <ui:include id="header" src="header.xhtml"/>
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="content">
                <ui:insert name="content" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
            <ui:insert name="bottom">
                <ui:include id="footer" src="footer.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Template client:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <ui:define name="title">City Setup</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="cityReviewform">
            ...
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

#### See also:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)

Comment: I guess its finally time to say thanks @BalusC after estimated 1000 ;) answers I read, which helped a lot! Thanks!